# JSTL fmt:formatNumber

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, scriptlet

How do I format a variable with <fmt:formatNumber> ? I'm learning JSTL and converting from old Struts tags. This doesn't work. It can't read the distance variable!

```
    <%double distance=geo.getDistance(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude(), lat, lng);%>
    <c:set var="distanceEL" value="${distance}"/>
    ${distance}, 
    <fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distance}"/>, 
    <fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distanceEL}"/>, 
    <fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="1234.567"/>,
    <%= new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distance) %>
```

It displays as

```
, , , 1234.6, 19.3
```

I'm using JSTL 1.2. So far I'm not impressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing oldschool [*scriptlets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) with [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and expecting that they share the same variable scope. This is not true. EL (those `${}` things) searches in respectively the [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html), [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), [session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and [application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) scopes for the first non-`null` attribute matching the given name and returns it. It does not access the *scriptlet* local scope in any way.

Basically, to make

```
<%double distance=geo.getDistance(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude(), lat, lng);%>
```

available as `${distance}`, you need to set it in any of the desired EL scopes, e.g. the request scope

```
<%
  double distance=geo.getDistance(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude(), lat, lng);
  request.setAttribute("distance", distance);
%>
```

Once done that, then you can just use

```html
<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distance}"/>
```

without the need to massage with `<c:set>`, by the way.

Note, a said, mixing *scriptlets* with EL is not the normal practice. You use the one or the other. In this particular case, that Java code belongs in a preprocessing [servlet class](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Also note that your concrete problem is not specifically related to [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). You just pointed it a non-existent variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish java variable to `${ExpressionLanguage}` you must add it to the context. There are application, session, request and page contexts. This is what happens in my test page.

- Using `<% ... %>` tags always indicates "heavy weight" java code, variables are not directly visible in JSTL code.
- introduce java variable to JSTL context such as pagecontext. Now you can use `${xx}` EL variables in jsp code.
- I did not put distance2 to a context, but using it through `<%= .. %>` embedded java scriptlet. Sometimes its just easiest to do this way.
- You even can introduce `${EL}`- only variable back to heavy weight java side, use `jsp:useBean` tag to create java variable. Then it can be seen in `<%..%>` scriptlets.
- I made a simple math expression inside `${distanceEL3}` value as an example.
- For you information, if use Tomcat look at the `tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp/org/apache/jsp/test_jsp.java` file. You can see how variables are created like was written java file by hand.

**test.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ 
    taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %><%@page 
    contentType="text/plain; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="java.text.*"
%><%

double distance=1234.567;
double distance2=3456.789;
pageContext.setAttribute("distance", distance);

%>Test Results

<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="page"/>

<c:set var="distanceEL" value="${distance}" />
distance=${distance}
fmt1=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distance}" />
fmt2=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.00" value="${distanceEL}" />
fmt3=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="1234.567" />
fmt4=<%= new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distance) %>

<c:set var="distanceEL2" value="<%= distance2 %>" />
distance2=${distanceEL2}
fmt1=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="<%= distance2 %>" />
fmt2=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.00" value="${distanceEL2}" />
fmt4=<%= new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distance2) %>

<c:set var="distanceEL3" value="${765.432-2.2}" />
<jsp:useBean id="distanceEL3" type="java.lang.Double" />
distance3=${distanceEL3}
fmt1=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="<%= distanceEL3 %>" />
fmt2=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.00" value="${distanceEL3}" />
fmt4=<%= new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distanceEL3) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

```
<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="<%=distance%>"/>
```

Which is weird, because I tried

```
<%= geo.getDistance(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude(), ${lat}, ${lng}) %>
```

which blew up. It's SO confusing! No where is it explained which has higher precedence, <%%> or ${}

Comment: I tried to learn the new normal, but this would not work: `<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${geo.getDistance(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude(), ${row.latitude}, ${row.longitude})}"/>`, nor would many, many variations.